# Silverlight Runtime Error 1001

Tags: silverlight, runtime-error

So I have a deployed Silverlight app that works fine on most client machines.  However, I have 1 client machine (Windows Vista / IE8) that throws the following javascript error:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0;
>   SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3;
>   OfficeLivePatch.0.0) Timestamp: Tue,
>   21 Jul 2009 14:38:15 UTC
>
> Message:
>   Sys.InvalidOperationException: Runtime
>   error 1001 in control 'Xaml1', method
>   : 1001 An error has occurred. Line:
>   453 Char: 17 Code: 0 
>   URI: www.DOMAINNAME.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=DYlfEE5ljRCaoM7uReLHHn6ek5uYaOA1UhTw1oJkABzHek2FGpt_ylvF5NNjuH26VVA5njj6q3r4MlWsNnz7ag2&t=1f1ca10

This is working fine on other Vista / IE8 machines and I cannot reproduce on my dev machine.

I am assuming this is a generic error message and the real details are not being displayed.  Based on the following link there is probably a way to access what is really going on, but I have no idea how.

https://silverlight.net/forums/p/99022/226122.aspx#226122

Comment: Yeah, those errors are generic and can be tough to debug.  Try looking at the http response using fiddler or http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper/ (my personal favorite) and see if you can get some more details about the error.  That's the technique that was used in the link you posted.

Comment: So i would have to install the http debugger (fiddler or webdevhelper) on the client machine since i cannot reproduce locally, correct?  This should work ok?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to install the tool on the client machine.

Comment: So i was just on the client machine and saw a bunch of http requests in WebDevHelper.  Since the error mentioned ScriptResource.axd=DYI... I viewed the details for that.  Line 453 is mentioned in the error, but the Response Content is only 52 lines.

The first line is:
// Name:        SilverlightControl.debug.js

I am very confused...

Comment: Any chance you could post the full error text?  Line 453 might be referring to the Xaml that's being loaded into the browser, did you check there?

Comment: I have same issue with SL on one just one Tablet.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the client. Try to play a bit with the network settings, maybe adding the domain name to trusted sites like explained in this post: http://mwearl.wordpress.com/2009/01/11/silverlight-error-1001-problem-solved/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if browser set in 'Compatible' mode. If yes, then you can try set the java script line into HEADER of your HTML/ASP page:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
```